# Vuetify v-menu gets badly positioned when I scroll down a tree view

Tags: vue.js, contextmenu

[image]

So We have this software running on chromium browser. And this treeview when un-expanded (when there is no scrollbar), the context menu position is correct. But, it starts misbehaving when we auto scrollbar comes into the screen.

```
<v-menu
      class="gsa-menu"
      v-model="contextMenu.show"
      :position-x="contextMenu.x"
      :position-y="contextMenu.y"
      absolute
      offset-y
      transition="false">


prepareContextMenu(item) {
  this.contextMenu.x = event.clientX;
  this.contextMenu.y = event.clientY - 40;
```

Comment: Can you create a [playground](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/) that reproduces the issue?